# Обьекты в C#

Tags: c#, объекты

Объясните кто может : вот у нас есть ссылка на объект который живёт в уп.куче, ссылка это просто адрес который хранится в стеке, при создании объекта под него выделяется память туда сразу заносятся локальные переменные класса, а что тогда такое объект-тип ? Вроде как только объект-тип хранит в себе методы и статические поля класса, но у меня ссылка только на "обычный" объект хотя могу использовать методы без всякого объекта-типа ! Подскажите где я ошибаюсь и в чём не прав ?
*немогу оставить комментарий пишу прямо в теме*

Глава 4. Основы типов (Рихтер via CLR 4.5)
1. Вычисление количества байтов, необходимых для хранения всех экземпляр-
ных полей типа и всех его базовых типов, включая System.Object (в котором
отсутствуют собственные экземплярные поля). Кроме того, в каждом объекте
кучи должны присутствовать дополнительные члены, называемые указателем
на **объект-тип** (type object pointer) и индексом блока синхронизации (sync block
index); они необходимы CLR для управления объектом. Байты этих дополни-
тельных членов добавляются к байтам, необходимым для размещения самого
объекта.
страница 135 :
На минуту отвлечемся на обсуждение объектов-типов. Как говорилось ранее
в этой главе, все объекты в куче содержат два дополнительных члена: указа-
тель на объект-тип и индекс блока синхронизации. В объектах типа Employee
и Manager оба эти члена присутствуют

Comment: Не совсем понимаю вашу терминологию. Под "локальные переменные класса", я так подозреваю, вы имеете в виду проперти?

Comment: обычные переменные без свойств, просто Рихтер пишет про какие-то объект-типы, а вот что это я так и не понял !

Comment: @SergeySharper, вы имеете в виду ValueTypes что ли? Если да, то про них есть очень хорошие дискуссии на этом форуме.

Comment: @SergeySharper что вы подразумеваете под "объектом-типом"? В C# нет такого термина. Если вы говорите, что это есть у Рихтера, то тогда пожалуйста процитируйте это его словами, и если не затруднит, то скажите, в какой главе и в каком разделе это написано

Comment: страница 138 :
Во-вторых, CLR проверяет у объекта внутренний указатель на объект-тип.
Затем CLR находит в таблице методов объекта-типа запись вызываемого метода,
обрабатывает код JIT-компилятором (при необходимости) и вызывает полученный
машинный код. В нашем случае вызывается реализация метода GenProgressReport
в Manager, потому что e ссылается на объект Manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я еще раз хотел бы повторить - никаких типов-объектов в C# не существует. Даже если вы откроете спецификацию языка, то вы не найдете в ней упоминания о type object pointer (если вдруг действительно захотите полистать спецификацию, то сделать это можно так: открываете папку, куда установлена Visual Studio, там находите папку VC#, в ней Specifications, затем 1033, в которой лежит англоязычная спецификация в виде Word-документа. У меня она находится в папке  ***c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\***  )

Дело тут в том, что как таковые эти типы-объекты не являются частью языка. Это особенность внутренней реализации CLR, которая, в принципе, должна быть скрыта от пользователей (то есть программистов). Как это всё функционирует на самом деле, я не знаю (возможно, этого точно не знает никто, кроме разработчиков из Microsoft),  более того, весьма возможно, что реализация этих внутренних особенностей  может быть разной в зависимости от реализации самой платформы и компилятора (нужно помнить, что помимо "обычной" реализации от Microsoft есть еще Xamarin со своим Mono (кроссплатформенным, между прочим)). Поэтому могу лишь предположить. Предположу я вот что. Если вы создаете экземпляр класса **Foo**, то весьма нелогично держать в нем (и в каждом другом создаваемом экземпляре) все методы (статические и экземплярные), поскольку они одинаковы для каждого инстанса. Следовательно, нужен этот самый "объект-тип", который хранит эти методы. Также предположу, что нестатические методы кроме своих параметров имеют скрытый параметр - указатель на экземпляр, вызывающий этот метод (насколько мне известно, нечто аналогичное есть в C++), а при вызове метода происходит проверка этого указателя на **null**. Следовательно, все взаимодействия экземпляра и объекта-типа происходят "за кулисами" C#, и разумеется, вам нет нужды помнить о существовании объекта-типа и как-то пытаться с ним взаимодействовать. Вот небольшой пример:

Допустим, есть простой класс

```
class Foo
{        
    public void Some()
    {            
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
    }
}
```

и метод, в котором он используется:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.Some();

        var foo2 = new Foo();
        foo2.Some();
    }
```

Посмотрим на IL-код, генерируемый из метода Main

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       28 (0x1c)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] class ConsoleTest.Foo foo, [1] class ConsoleTest.Foo foo2)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void ConsoleTest.Foo::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldloc.0
  IL_0008:  callvirt   instance void ConsoleTest.Foo::Some()
  IL_000d:  nop
  IL_000e:  newobj     instance void ConsoleTest.Foo::.ctor()
  IL_0013:  stloc.1
  IL_0014:  ldloc.1
  IL_0015:  callvirt   instance void ConsoleTest.Foo::Some()
  IL_001a:  nop
  IL_001b:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Нас в нем интересуют строки **IL_0007** и **IL_0008**. В первой мы видим, что командой **ldloc.0** в стек заносится адрес локальной переменной под индексом 0 (это переменная foo, как можно видеть из секции **.locals init**). Во второй строке можно видеть, что происходит вызов метода **Foo::Some()**. Для какого экземпляра? Ведь в коде **instance void ConsoleTest.Foo::.ctor()** нет явного указания. Для того, чей адрес лежит на вершине стека, то есть foo. Аналогичные действия происходят и в строках **IL_0014** и **IL_0015**, но уже для foo2. А метод между прочим вызывается из одного и того же адреса - **ConsoleTest.Foo::Some()**

Ну и напоследок маленькая ремарка. Как я говорил выше, при вызове нестатического метода сначала проверяется, что передаваемый в метод скрытый параметр - указатель на вызывающий экземпляр не равен null. В этом проявляется одно отличие C# скажем от С++. В С++ такой код

```
    class Foo {
       public :
       void DoSomething() {
            cout << "Hello world!";
        }
    };

    // ------

   Foo* foo = 0;
   foo->DoSomething();
```

вполне может сработать (хотя вообще чреват undefined behavior) потому что несмотря на равенство указателя нулю, в методе DoSomething не используются нестатические члены класса. А вот в C# подобный код выкинет NullReferenceException вне зависимости от использования/неиспользования экземплярных членов (хотя с помощью синтаксического сахара методов расширения этого можно избежать)

Comment: думаю, можно просто сказать, что "объект-тип" это просто [таблица виртуальных методов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2). Просто это Майкрософт, они любят придумывать терминологию.

Comment: я вообще не уверен, что объект-тип - это чья-то терминология, кроме Рихтера

Comment: @DreamChild, Спасибо вам за обьяснения ! Вы нереально круто разбираетесь в этой теме ... Видать у вас большой опыт !!!

Comment: Пожалуйста) На самом деле у меня не такой большой опыт) И не настолько круто я разбираюсь - здесь есть люди гораздо круче меня (нет, это не ложная скромность)

Comment: @KoVadim Таблица Виртуальных Методов - это часть объекта типа. В нём еще есть ссылка на метаданные (то что отдает метод GetType()), прочая сервисная информация (вроде был ли вызван статический конструктор)

Comment: @Олег Нечитайло, а Вы думаете, что к примеру С++ компилятор подобного не добавляет? Просто он может это хорошо вырезать. Делают это и другие компиляторы/интерпретаторы. И не парятся, пишут "runtime информация" или что то подобное. А Рихтер видимо решил написать красиво, не как у всех. 

**юмор:**

Наверное только Си компилятор подобного не делает. Но если бы был на .NET платформе, то его бы заставили:)